# pyspark databricks code to check zero byte json file

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks

my master notebook identifies the JSON file and calls the zeroByteCheck function. my zeroByteCheck function should check the incoming file whether it has data or not, if it has data then it should call another function, or else it should stop the process and email. please help me with the code.

```
def ZeroByteCheck(path):
  data =spark.read.json(path)
  if(len(data.head(1))==0):
      email();
  else:
      function();
def function(path):
  print("file is not null")
def email():
  print("zerobyte file, sending an email")
```

is this the correct way of pyspark code?

Comment: no, we can't, without your trying effort...

Comment: I'm not strong in pyspark coding, have tried to code. can u help me with it?

Comment: isn't that as simple as `if spark.read.json(path).count() == 0:`?

Comment: how to insert the json file size to error table in databricks? is their any command to fecth the size of the file and move it to error table

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the path, and you're using Databricks, you can check them as follow:

```py
# check 0 records
spark.read.json(path).count()

# check file size
dbutils.fs.ls(path)
# Output
# [FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/my_file.txt', name='my_file.txt', size=40)]
```